# Not able to add "IN" and "Out" mediator in a sequence

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am creating a sequence in the WSO2 developer studio but I am not able to get IN and OUT mediator in the Palette . But If I create a sequence directly in ESB itself then there I am able to add IN and OUT mediator .

Can any please suggest whether IN and OUT mediator are supported in a sequence in WSO2 developer studio through palette view.

below is the code that i am trying to create a sequence in WSO2 studio.

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="MessageChannel" trace="enable">
    <in>
        <send>
            <endpoint>
                <address uri="http://localhost:8081/Hello_world"></address>
            </endpoint>
        </send>
    </in>
    <out>
        <send></send>
    </out>
</sequence>
```

Regards,
Vikas

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be confused: this looks more like a proxy configuration and not a sequence. A proxy contains 3 sequences: in, out and fault.

Answer (score 0):

Please note in WSO2 Developer Studio it supports IN and OUT mediators only in main sequence.